# Redux state update

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

When I try to register with redux, everything is fine, but there is a problem.isCreated turns to true after alert shows up.What should I do to fix this ?

```
handleKayit = e => {
e.preventDefault();
const { adi_soyadi,kul_adi,cep_tel, cinsiyet,egitim,dog_tarihi,dogdugu_il,isi,yasadigi_kent,e_posta,parola } = this.state;
const { dispatch } = this.props;
dispatch(register(adi_soyadi,kul_adi,cep_tel,undefined, cinsiyet,egitim,dog_tarihi,dogdugu_il,isi,yasadigi_kent,e_posta,undefined,undefined,undefined,parola,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined));
const { isCreated} = this.props;
if (isCreated){
  alert("Successful signup")
  window.location.reload();
  this.props.isCreated.push(false);
}else{
  alert("Error on signup")
}
```

}

**this is the reducer **

```
    import { REGISTER_SUCCESS,REGISTER_ERROR} from "../actions/uyekayitAction";


const initState = {
    uye: '',
    isCreated: false,
    error: false,
    errorMessage: '',
}

const uyekayitReducer = (state= initState,action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                uye: action.uye,
                isCreated: true,
                error: false,
                errorMessage: ''
            };
        case REGISTER_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                uye: '',
                error: true,
                isCreated: false,
                errorMessage: action.error
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }}

export default uyekayitReducer;
```

**And this is the action**

```
    import uyekayitService from '../services/uyekayitService';
let now = new Date();

export const REGISTER_SUCCESS = "REGISTER_SUCCESS";
export const REGISTER_ERROR = "REGISTER_ERROR";

const registerSuccess = uye => {
    return {
        type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        uye
    };
};

const registerError = error => {
    return {
        type: REGISTER_ERROR,
        error
    };
};

export const register = (adi_soyadi,kul_adi,cep_tel,avatar="bos", cinsiyet,egitim,dog_tarihi,dogdugu_il,isi,yasadigi_kent,e_posta,s_medya1="bos",s_medya2="bos",s_medya3="bos",parola,rol="kullanici",icerik_sayisi=0,yorum_sayisi=0,uyelik_tarihi=now,songiris=now) => {
    return dispatch => {
        uyekayitService.register(adi_soyadi,kul_adi,cep_tel,avatar, cinsiyet,egitim,dog_tarihi,dogdugu_il,isi,yasadigi_kent,e_posta,s_medya1,s_medya2,s_medya3,parola,rol,icerik_sayisi,yorum_sayisi,uyelik_tarihi,songiris)
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.message)
                data.message
                    ? dispatch(registerError(data.message))
                    : (dispatch(registerSuccess(data)))

            })
            .catch(err => dispatch(registerError(err)));
    }
}
```

**like I said this is working well but isCreated changes after alert shows up so even if register is succesful it shows error on signup because isCreated changes after alert how can I fix this ? **

Comment: How can we know? What is `isCreated`? Is it from your store? What does your reducer and action look like? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Your question is not clear.You have to mention the data types of the data which with you are facing the problems and also you should include the reducer .

Comment: I changed the question